# Can't access scope from the directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('rankingTags', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.updateTagList = function(tag) {
          console.log('updateTagList function called') // never logged
        };
      },

      templateUrl: '/app/common/directives/tags.tpl.html',
      replace: true
    };
  });
```

Template for the directive:

```
<div class="tag" ng-repeat="tag in $root.collection.tags track by $index">
  <input ng-click="updateTagList(tag)" type="checkbox" />
  <label>{{tag.name}}</label>
</div>
```

Calling directive from another template:

```
<ranking-tags></ranking-tags>
```

I can't access `updateTagList` function from the directive template. So somehow this controller isn't linked to the template.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: why is `'NodeJs'` in quotes? Can't 2-way bind to a string. What is intent there? Also why is repeat looking for `$root` when the collection of tags is already passed into directive?

Comment: Suggest you create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: @charlietfl `tags` list passed to the directive is empty. `updateTagList` function updates it, and then you can catch changes with `$watch` in the page controller. `$root.collection.tags` ($rootScope value) on the other hand has a list of tags.

Comment: you are passing tags into the directive and 2-way binding it, why are you using $root too? Is $root.collection.tags different from the tags you are passing in?

Comment: shouldn't be using `$rootScope` to store that data in the first place. Where's the demo?

Comment: @ajmajmajma Look at the comment before yours. Now I removed `tag` from the directive parameters so there should be no more confusions.

Comment: @MikeVayvala removing it makes no sense. Now you have no `$scope.tags` in directive. Seems like your problem is higher up in binding `tags` to scope

Comment: @charlietfl the problem is that I can not access `updateTagList` function from the directive template. ($rootScope, $watch or tags does not matter)

Comment: @MikeVayvala you have said that but where is the demo that replicates this? Again I think your problem is higher up in the app and perhaps a bit of misunderstanding of isolated scopes

Comment: @charlietfl check the update

Comment: stop changing the code. All that does is add confusion from the initial starting point of the question. removing scope items from isolated scope object isn't going to solve your problem ... it will make it worse unless you get rid of isolated scope entirely

Comment: I simplified the example.

Comment: There is no reason in code shown that `updateTagList` would not be available. You need to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want further help. How hard is it to stick some of this in plunker and show us?

Comment: @charlietfl here: http://plnkr.co/edit/4LPbx09NWEYjBhyroqmM?p=preview

Comment: Remove replace: true, you can add transclude: true if you would like.

Comment: @charlietfl it works now. But why `replace: true` brakes it?

Comment: I made a sample using an argument to send the tag list to directive: http://jsbin.com/reroce/edit?html,js,output . Here the called function is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need `replace: true` (this is what is breaking your function), instead you can use `transclude:true` if you like. Replace is depricated.

from the change -

> The replace flag for defining directives that replace the element that
>   they are on will be removed in the next major angular version. This
>   feature has difficult semantics (e.g. how attributes are merged) and
>   leads to more problems compared to what it solves. Also, with
>   WebComponents it is normal to have custom elements in the DOM.

AFAIK it is not removed but the known bugs are not fixed, you can check out the thread here if you are interested further. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/eec6394a342fb92fba5270eee11c83f1d895e9fb#commitcomment-8124407

Answer (score 0):

`$root.collection.tags` should simply be just `tags` since the scope of the template is already the `$scope` of the directive.

Comment: `$root.collection.tags` is from a `$rootScope`